# Schedule for opening a text file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, fedora

I'm a newbie in Linux and just stared to learn about it for couple of days. There are something that confused me about "at" command. How can i open a text file at a fixed time by using "at" and "gedit" command ?
TY

Comment: `gedit` is primarily an interactive command, and as such is not suitable for use with `at`.   What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: For example: i want to open a text file name 'new' at 5 PM everyday

Comment: use crontab with nano or vi (vim)

Comment: i tried crontab with nano, vi and none of them worked.

Comment: What do you want to edit in a file ? Give some example code and file structure. You can use `sed` and `at` together.

Comment: It does not make sense to open a file with an interactive editor usin `at`.  The purpose of `at` is to run things without human interaction.  The purpose of an interactive editor is to enable human interaction.  What do you want to do to the file when you open it?  What does "open a text file" mean to you?